# let cgi-fcgi command fail on bad status code

Tags: fastcgi, fpm

I am trying to write a health check for kubernetes. The application runs with fpm-php, so it needs to be fcgi.

I have this script

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

fcgi_env=(
  SCRIPT_NAME=/var/www/html/public/index.php
  SCRIPT_FILENAME=/var/www/html/public/index.php
  REMOTE_ADDR=127.0.0.1
  REQUEST_METHOD=GET
  REQUEST_URI="$1"
  PATH_INFO="$1"
)

env -i "${fcgi_env[@]}" cgi-fcgi -bind -connect 127.0.0.1:9000
```

The problem is that this shows me headers and body, but I am interested in the status code or more specifically I want it to fail, if the status code is greater than 299.

I can set some custom header and grep for that and so on, but I would like a more solid approach. So the question is, how do I retrieve the status code or even better have it fail on a bad status similar to curls --fail option?

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/EekoS/php-fpm-cli

Comment: @NetVicious, I rolled my own. Well heavily based on the work of someone else https://github.com/wolf-gmbh/fcgi-probe